# Mysql - optimal indexing for query using IN operator

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE foo IN (1,2,3,4) AND bar = 123;
```

I have 3 indices:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_foo (foo);

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_bar (bar);

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_foo_bar (foo, bar);
```

When I try `EXPLAIN` with the query, `IDX_bar` is chosen which I don't understand why. So my questions are:

- Why is `IDX_bar` chosen but not `IDX_foo` or `IDX_foo_bar`?
- Does MySQL choose index differently depend on the data at the time?
- Should I only have `IDX_bar` and remove the other two?

Comment: Depends on the data and statistics. If for example foo only ever contains values 1-4, or very few others, there’s no point in using an index containing it when you can just index with bar

Comment: `(foo,bar)` will be the same as `(foo)`. If you want a multi-column one which works for this query you need `(bar,foo)`. Which one to use depends on how many foo's per bar and vice versa (as @sami noted).

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208660/mysql-optimal-indexing-for-query-using-in-operator

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX(bar, foo)`.  That is, put the one with the `=` first.

Older versions of MySQL had less smarts.  The above index is likely to be the best, or at least tie with the best, for all versions of MySQL.

General lesson on building MySQL indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Your specific questions:

- Why is IDX_bar chosen but not IDX_foo or IDX_foo_bar? -- `=` is the best for optimizing.
- Does MySQL choose index differently depend on the data at the time? -- Yes (but not very often).  For example, if `bar` is infrequently `123`, any index starting with `bar` is likely to be useful.  If it is frequently `123`, then the bouncing back and forth between the index and the data may be more costly than the benefit from the index.  (The cutoff varies, but is typically around 20%.)
- Should I only have IDX_bar and remove the other two? -- Toss your 3, keep mine.  However, some *other* query may benefit from one of yours.

Note: `INDEX(bar)` is redundant if you have `INDEX(bar, foo)`; get rid of the former.

(Most of what I said here is in that link.)